# fatal error call to undefined function method repairReportsController::doAction()

Tags: php

Hi so I'm pretty new to php and i'm trying to get a response from a post request but all i get is a 500 error and Fatal error: Call to undefined method repairReportsController::doAction()

here's my code

```
class repairReportsController
{

function postRepair( $request ){

    print_r($request);

    if ( isset( $request->parameters ) ) {
        $parameters = $request->parameters;
        if ( isset( $parameters['getId'] ) ) {
            $userId = $parameters['getId'];
        }
    }
    print_r($request->parameters);
  }
}
```

This is the doAction() is call but works with other controllers.

```
$result = $controller->doAction($request);
```

Comment: HI there, the code is in a completely different file and works with all other controllers so i didn't think that it was necessary however i will add it now

Comment: Where is doAction() function in your class? It can't be called if it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Jocelyn is right, it looks like you're trying to `extend` a framework controller, but you're missing that from your class definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class definition doesn't seem to include the function you are calling.

You must either include the function in the class `repairReportsController`, or if the function already exists in a parent class you need to add the `extends` keyword to your class (only if it makes sense to extend from the other class).

Read [PHP Classes and Objects - the basics](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) for more information.